# python requests library - get part of response

Tags: python, python-requests

How can i get a part of response of get/post-request from python-requests library? I need get URL content and analys it fast, but web-server may return a very large response (500Mb for example).

Answer (score 2):

Set `stream` to True.

```
example_url = 'http://www.example.com/somethingbig'
r = requests.get(example_url, stream=True)
```

At this point only the response headers have been downloaded and the connection remains open.

Documentation: [body-content-workflow](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)